# How do I encode a 2D Tensor to a PNG image with Tensorflow.js + Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

Suppose I have a tensor like this:

```js
let myTensor = tf.tensor([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]);
```

According to the Tensorflow.js API docs, I can use [`tf.node.encodePng`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/latest/#node.encodePng) to convert a Tensor to a PNG. The docs claim this about the parameters thereof:

> Parameters:
>
> - `image` (Tensor3D) A 3-D uint8 Tensor of shape [height, width, channels].
> - `compression` (number) An optional int. Defaults to -1. Compression level. Optional

In this case, I would assume that I could encode my Tensor to a PNG like so:

```js
let myImage = await tf.node.encodePng(myTensor.cast("uint8"));
```

However, this causes the following crash:

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to cast to unknown dtype uint8
    at cast_ (.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:5093:15)
    at Object.cast (.../ingester/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4186:29)
    at Tensor.cast (.../ingester/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:2181:26)
```

According to the [documentation for the cast method](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/2.3.0/#cast), `uint8` is not a valid type for a Tensor.

**How can I convert a 2D Tensor with a type of `float32` to a PNG image?**

Answer (score 0):

`uint8` is not a supported type for `tf tensor`. However when the data is downloaded from the backend it can be a typedArray of type `uint8`.

The arguments of `tf.node.encodePng` is a 3d tensor. So the 2d tensor needs first to be reshaped as 3d